# Videos of interacting art (from two different types of art genres)

Tags: video, video-editor, video-quality, video-capture

I was unsure about whether to post this on the Computer Graphics stack exchange. I could also have chosen the Graphic Design stack exchange or the Arts & Crafts stack exchange.

However, as you will be reading this question, you will realize that the first night be a good but incomplete fit, and that the best place to post this is here.

I am interested in the scenario where a graphics designer and an artist (really, two types of different artists, A and B), depict, graphics, in different styles.

Now imagine that one of them goes and draws on the other's art, and give versa. Each artist just draws in their specific style.

When the eye sees this, (and hears what the artists say), the brain produces certain neurotrasmitter release interactions.

This leads me to think about how different videos would interact, if each video projected, a different kind of area in the other's with is own style.

More generally, just suppose there is one video with two styles, interacting with each other (the interaction can occur in a variety of ways).

If the video is about what is produced by the brain before pleasure, and after pleasure, in graphics, the video can be used to produce an analyzation of what is in the cloud in the user's brain after certain types, of, pleasure.

So, this describes a little bit of what I am looking for.

So, the question is, what types of video interaction can be achieved between two different types of arts using modern video editing, animation, and prediction, techniques, to produce, an art video (of this sort)?

What has been done in this area, what examples and types of examples (example, categories) of this thing exist, (even from a technical point of view)?

As I explained, this question is about art videos, rather than just art, and how computer science told support this, either by starting from pictures of painings, or creating the entire thing in the computer.

Thanks.